# How to move Resultset curser via button click, and display data in textfields?

Tags: sqlite, javafx, cursor, fxml, resultset

So, I'm creating a desktop banking application. It's nothing too serious, I'm just trying to practice and get better.

```
// Method I use to get a connection. I know this works.
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    String sCon = "jdbc:sqlite:banking.sqlite";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sCon);
    return connection;
}
.
..
... 
.....Other code
```

Method I attempt to use to create and manipulate the data in the result set.
The problem I believe starts here. With this code, I am only able to return one row of the result set and only the last row.

```
public static Customers getAccounts(Customers c) {

    String query = "select RowCount, Customers.Account_Number, "
            + "Customers.First_Name, Last_Name, Address, "
            + "Phone_Number, Accounts.Balance "
            + "from Customers "
            + "join Accounts ";
    try (Connection connection = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

        while (rs.next()) {

            String fName = rs.getString("First_Name");
            String lName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
            String address = rs.getString("Address");
            String phone = rs.getString("Phone_Number");
            String accNum = rs.getString("Account_Number");
            String balance = rs.getString("Balance");


            c.setFirstName(fName);
            c.setLastName(lName);
            c.setAddress(address);
            c.setPhoneNumber(phone);
            c.setAccountNumber(accNum);
            c.setBalance(balance);

        }
        return c;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Here is the method that is linked to the button I use to perform what I'm trying to attempt. It's part of the Controller class. I believe this method is also a part of the problem. Any ideas? Thank for all you guys do. This website is a real benefit to the community.

```
public void next() {
   Customers c = new Customers();
   DBInterface.getAccounts(c);

    firstNameF2.setText(c.getFirstName());
    lastNameF2.setText(c.getLastName());
    addressF2.setText(c.getAddress());
    phoneNumberF2.setText(c.getPhoneNumber());
    accNumF.setText(c.getAccountNumber());
    balanceF.setText(c.getBalance());

}
```

Comment: Even though the class name `Customers` suggests containing information about multiple customers, you use it as if it contains only the information about a single customer... Also your code wouldn't allow you to check, if there was a single row returned by the query...

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to get multiple `Customers` objects, then you definitely should return a list of that.

```
public static List<Customers> getAccounts() {
    // Whatever you originally had...

    final List<Customers> ret = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        String fName = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String lName = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String address = rs.getString("Address");
        String phone = rs.getString("Phone_Number");
        String accNum = rs.getString("Account_Number");
        String balance = rs.getString("Balance");

        final Customers cust = new Customers();

        cust.setFirstName(fName);
        cust.setLastName(lName);
        cust.setAddress(address);
        cust.setPhoneNumber(phone);
        cust.setAccountNumber(accNum);
        cust.setBalance(balance);

        ret.add(cust);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I have removed the part about passing in the instance of `Customers` (which would have ended up as passing in `List<Customers>`. If you really need to do that, you can add back in and do all the necessary checks.

Comment: I used a customers object, instead of a List, because I don't know how get the take the data from a List and display it to the text fields. However, I can use a customers object, to hold the information, then use the Getters and setters methods to display the information to the textfields.  I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but as a beginner this is what I have so far. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: @YussufClark If you have 100 customers, and you want to display the name, how are you going to display 100 customers' names in one field?